# Closing connection to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a question about closing connection in C#. Company has an application where data flows automatically online from app to DB. I would like to create my own ASP + C# application which will use select from data (DB table which is filled from company app) as source for independent report. My question: can closing of the connection in my app have influence on the second(company, very important app?) - record will miss in db due to close connection? or any other problems?

Comment: Closing your connection should have no effect on any other connections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, everything will be safe if you close it properly. I recommend you to use `using` construction always. It will be transformed into try-catch-finally and close resources automatically.

Answer (score 5):

That totally depends on your use-case, if you open and leave open hundreds and hundreds if not thousands and thousands of empty connections, the SQL Server will slowly begin to have some performance degradation.

Think of it as you asking your boss for something, and you say, "Boss-man, I need to ask you a question." But you remind him hundreds and thousands of times a second, "I need to ask you a question." Anything else he tries to do will slowly begin to lose performance, as he has to process the fact that you are going to have to ask him a question. Similarly with Sql Server. *Mind you, at this point you haven't **actually** asked your question yet.*

If your DBMS is Microsoft SQL Server, see this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187030.aspx

> SQL Server allows a maximum of 32,767 user connections.

If you open 32k connections to the server, two things will likely happen:

1. Your DBA will come to you and say "wtf mate?" by the time you get close. A likely argument will ensue in which case you and the DBA will probably end up yelling and creating a scene.
2. Your DBMS will reach the maximum connection limit and the other all will crap out.

Not saying that any of this will happen, that requires you to open `32,767` *concurrent* connections, but it just goes to further prove that you should open/close as required. Also, if your Application uses a pool of connections and you open `n` connections, and the pool limit (separate from SQL Server - mind you) is `n`, you just stopped your app from opening more.

Generally speaking, you should **open** your connections as *late* as possible, and **close** them as *early* as possible.